# Maximize an UserControl without using a form

Tags: c#, forms

My project built a panel with a pictureBox. This panel should be possible to maximize (for pictures displaying). I want to do that by creating a class like that:

`public partial class ImageDisplay : UserControl`

and in designer I add a picturebox and later do something with that.

It's not working properly, coz I cannot maximize ImageDisplay class (while it inherits by UserControl). I tried to do that just by changing it on:
`public partial class ImageDisplay : Form`
and then change the form's properties.

But I can't do that in that way, coz after I built my project, I use created `.dll` file in another program. And this program is working properly, when I use the class inheriting from UserControl. But when it inherits from the form, this program crushs.
I don't know why that is working in that way, I just get this code yesterday, when I've never coded in C# before.

So every hint or help or maybe good link would be helpful.

Comment: Form and UserControl is like Car and an Engine. Build as UserControl, when you drop you ImageDisplay control somewhere change its property Dock = Fill.

Comment: But UserControl doesn't have a property like dock.

Comment: Are you [sure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Oh, so how I can get to it? Coz when I'm looking to properties there is only [this](http://i.imgur.com/yXmn6uR.png)

Comment: LIN_SSH is your control, when you drop it somewhere then you can find this property. Like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5L_q_jI494&feature=youtu.be&t=469).

Comment: I have a proxy, can't go to yt... :(

Comment: After you build project where your user control is, in toolbox LIN_SSH control will become available. Drag and from it on the form, now see properties and try to change Dock - you'll see result.

Comment: Oh, but I don't build it in another program, I just built it in visual studio, and later drop `.dll` file to this program, you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/twpwhaf.png) `ReplayPanel.dll` so I don't have a toolbox or something like that here

Comment: Not all properties are visible in the designer. Put this in the constructor of your UC: `Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: So it looks like this control is loaded dynamically by another app. If you're not in control of that app code, then your question is too broad to answer. Sorry.

Comment: Reniuz, thanks for idea, TaW, this works great, thank you too.